# Remove file from Mercurial repository without distribute a deletion

Tags: mercurial

In my repository somebody committed files that should be unknown (or ignored, according the .hgignore file).

**How can I tell to Mercurial to no longer track those files but leave the files as unknown (or ignored) on remote working copies?** (With remote working copies I mean working copies of the other users of the repository.)

More details: Specifically those files are .classpath and .project generated by Eclipse IDE when the project was imported as Maven/Gradle project. They have been added to the repository and committed. I want to do not track changes of that files but I don't want to ask everybody to re-import the project into Eclipse again. Renaming .classpath and .project  to .classpath.template and .project.template does not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is tricky, as the file will be stored as deleted in the changelog when you tell hg to forget it - and on update it will be deleted in the working dirs of everyone who pulls and updates to a rev later than the one where those files have been removed from tracking.

If you can get by with everyone using `hg revert -rTRACKED FILENAME` where TRACKED is the changeset where the files are (still) tracked, it is not really nice but probably the easiest solution.

You might want to add all files you do not want to be ever tracked to add to your .hgignore so that these won't be added by `hg addremove` accidentially.

Comment: Instead to ask them to issue not really nice tricks, I told them to use Eclipse to regenerate the files upon deletions. Yes, the files are yet in the .hgignore but they say it didn't work proper. I wander what client they're using... Anyway thanks.